c# epoll low throughput
I am trying to develop high load net udp library on c# for my server. I am now investigating most efficient way to read data from socket. As far as i know epoll/iocp must be the best way of doing that, however while stress testing I am facing a problem of low bandwidth.
Here is code that is responsible for reading data from socket.
public void Start(int startPort, int portsNumber)
        {
            _packets = new BuffersPool.Buffer[_packetsSize];
            _pool = new BuffersPool(100_000, 1500);
            for (int i = 0; i < portsNumber; ++i)
            {
                var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                socket.ReceiveBufferSize = 262144;
                EndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, startPort + i);
                socket.Bind(remoteEndPoint);

                var buffer = _pool.GetBuffer();
                var e = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
                e.SetBuffer(buffer.array, 0, 1500);
                e.RemoteEndPoint = remoteEndPoint;
                e.Completed += OnIOCompleted;
                e.UserToken = buffer;
                socket.ReceiveFromAsync(e);
            }
        }

        private void OnIOCompleted(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
            {
                Socket socket = (Socket)sender;
                do
                {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref _realPacketsReceived);
                    var idx = Interlocked.Increment(ref _packetsIndex) % _packetsSize;
                    _packets[idx] = (BuffersPool.Buffer)e.UserToken;
                    var newBuffer = _pool.GetBuffer();
                    e.SetBuffer(newBuffer.array, 0, 1500);
                    e.UserToken = newBuffer;
                } while (!socket.ReceiveFromAsync(e));
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError($"Socket error {e.SocketError}");
            }

            Interlocked.Add(ref _time, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

There is a side class that takes all collected packets once per 100ms and i count packets I was able to receive. I have deployed it on a linux server with 16 cores 8gb RAM and opened 16 ports. And i implemented test clients that just send a huge amount of packets to server.
As a result my server can receive maximum 2.5million of 300 bytes packets per 10 seconds. For me it looks too slow, there are multiple articles in net where people are able to receive millions packets per second. Moreover when i test code that reads data synchronously, it works x5-6 times faster, that is counterintuitive for me. And synchoronous reading loads processor less (about 600% vs 1000% of epoll).
I set up a huge socket buffer on server and i checked with linux tools that kernel drops no packets, so the problem is somewhere else. I also checked with tcpdump that packets from clients actually come to server machine, and the problem is that my code cant process all of them fast enough and they 'disappear'.|
I also measured time spent in OnIOCompleted callback and its around 1 sec per 10 seconds of 'client ddosing' (3.5 million packets come per 10 sec). (_time field). Increasing number of ports gives no result.
Maybe c# SyncEventArgs wrap of epoll is too slow or scales for much bigger amount of packets than i am trying to test? Or am I using it in a wrong way?

What bandwidth are you using? 1 Gbps ethernet? Full use of 1 Gbps ethernet bandwidth with full 1500 octet payload per fame yields about 81,274 fps. Do the math: ethernet overhead will be 38 octets plus the 1500 octets of payload time eight bits per octet is 12,304 bits per frame. I,000,000,000 bits per second divided by 12,304 bits per frame is 81,274.38 fps. Also, I think you mean "throughput," not "bandwidth" which is a function of your NIC.

Yes, but I am using 300 bytes packets, not 1500, so according to your calculations i must get around 4million packets per 10 sec and they really come to server machine (i see it in tcpdump) but only a half of them (2.5 million as I mentioned above) is processed by server.

Are the two hosts on the same network, and is the network possible oversubscribed? Packet loss is inevitable, but you do not detail. the network to see where that may be. Also, you can send to many packets to the interface with UDP, exceeding the interface bandwidth, causing dropped packets.

Hosts are on different networks. Server is deployed on Digital Ocean and clients are started by me and my colleagues on different computers from different locations. The problem is that packets are not lost. I see in tcpdump that server machine accepts 4 million packets and kernel drops none of them. I dont think, that 1.5million packets can be lost somewhere in kernel while it goes from nic to server app.
